# Google API keys for different API (Android)

Tags: android, api, key

Do I need to generate a new API key for each API of Google that I'm using?

For example, I have currently Google Maps API in my app and now I want to add the Google Maps Geolocation API. Can I use the same api key for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each API requires a new key.

You can do that here:

[Google Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/android/)

Comment: I don't know why this answer is accepted (maybe it was true when it was accepted), but you can use same API key for multiple APIs as long as restrictions on API key are satisfied.